# how to detect which textview is being edited swift

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I've got two textviews on my view and I want them both to be editable.

But each one pertains to a different record in my database.

How would I be able to detect which textView is being edited?

Here is my code so far

```
  func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) { //Handle the text changes here
    if(textView.textAlignment == .Center){
        PFUser.currentUser()!["bio"] = textView.text
        PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()
    }
    else{
        PFUser.currentUser()!["displayName"] = textView.text
        PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()
    }
}
```

What I'm currently doing is detecting if the view is right aligned or center aligned to be able to tell them apart.
This works but it's not ideal as I'd like to have both of them center aligned. But I'm unaware which field in the textView object would contain an ID or some method of identification as to which textView the function was called for.

Comment: Do you have properties (IBOutlets) for each of the text views? If so, just compare the text view that was provided to the delegate method with the properties to see which one it is

Comment: Yes I've created IBOutlets for each textview but what do you mean by compare the textview properties?   Such as if (textView == t_view1) ? Assuming t_view1 is the IBOutlet variable to a specific textview.

Comment: Also you can assign different `tags` to `textView` and check it in your `delegate` as `textView.tag`.

Comment: You can simply check by `textView == textViewOne` if you made `textViewOne` as `iboutlet` isnt it....Its only hard if you dont have reference to it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you have properties that refer to the two text views you can simply see which one was passed to your delegate and act accordingly:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) { //Handle the text changes here

    guard let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() else {
        return
    }
    if (textView == self.bioTextView){
        currentUser["bio"] = textView.text
        currentUser.saveInBackground()
    } else {
        currentUser["displayName"] = textView.text
        currentUser.saveInBackground()
    }
}
```