# How to get all custom tableview cell textField and textView value outside tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I tried to access custom tableView cell textfield from outside tableView like this :

```
for i in 0..<NameCounter {
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
guard let cell = sampleTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? sampleCellView else{
    return
}
if let text = cell.txtName.text, !text.isEmpty {
   let value = text
   print("Getting NameText : \(value)")
}

if let text = cell.txtNote.text, !text.isEmpty {
    let value = text
    print("Getting noteText : \(value)")
}}
```

But the problem is above method you can only get visible cell of tableView except cell is nil. and because I guard it to avoid nil cell, I did not get all textfield value.

If I remove the guard like this :

```
let cell = sampleTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! sampleCellView
```

It will crash and got some cell is nil.

How to access all textfield value from outside tableView and got all cell (cell maynot nil)?

I have multiple tableView, and inside each tableView cell, I put txtName and txtNote. I want to detect which txtName and txtNote is being edited, so I can put in the right model.

note: txtName is textfield and txtNote is textView

Comment: Of course it will crash, because if you have for instance first 10 cells on screen, but there are 50 cells - it's very possible that cells in range [11...50] are nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This return

```
let cell = sampleTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! sampleCellView
```

nil and crash for any cell that's not visible as of the fact that the table cells are reusable , you need to save the user typing for each cell to model  ( tableView dataSource array ), then get the values from it

```
var model = [String]()
```

// inside cellForRowAt

```
    cell.textView.delegate = self

    cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row
}
@objc func textViewDidChange(_ tex: UITextView) {


    model[tex.tag] = tex.text!

}
```

class VC:UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate {

Comment: How to save the user typing for each cell to model? Use textFieldDidChange?

Comment: did you mean var model = [String]()

Comment: how about if txtNote is a textView, not a textField?

Comment: the problem is I have multiple tableView and inside each tableView, I have txtNote. How to detect which txtNote is being edited (from which tableView)? I found this but this textView not inside tableView cell (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625944/how-to-detect-which-textview-is-being-edited-swift)

Comment: your previous answer about textField is right, I think you can keep that on answer so other also can see the right answer. because txtName is textField and txtNote is textView. and each tableView have each txtName and txtNote. And I have multiple tableView.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rely on the values being taken from the cell labels, text fields etc.

Once a cell goes off-screen - it gets thrown to a pool for later reuse, and it may even get deallocated.

You should keep the `view state` inside some array, and then you can SAFELY get any value at any index.

If you have 1000 cells, perhaps only 10-20 will be visible at any time, and maybe 40-50 or so in the reusable cells pool. If you are at index path row 100 - obviously the cells after index path row 150 will be `nil`.

Comment: If I use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, I did not get any cell textfield value

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will give you a cell, but it could contain text labels from previously displayed cell, and then you should still configure it with data from the Model for the specific section / row, which can be as simple as an array of dictionary objects. You should not rely on getting data from views, but from models.

Answer (score 0):

As a good standard practise, there should be no need to get values from the `UITableViewCells`. You should instead get the values from the Model that is presented in the `UITableView`, based on some logic as per the need.

Further, when it is needed to access any text that was typed on `UITableViewCell`, then it should be updated in the associated model first and should be accessed from there.

Behind the scene UITableViewCell are re-used and only the cells currently visible will show you actual data if you access it from UITableView. Hence persisting cell's entered values to some array / dictionary for later use is the option.

Comment: I think OP is asking about how to update that model.

Comment: the actual condition is the nil cell have textfield text and it is not empty

Comment: how to use model like you wrote @Rizwan ?

Comment: Are you using some array / dictionary to show its content in the tableview ?. If not then make an array and save the content of the UITableViewCell after user enters in to it. Then access the corresponding data from the Array.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri - update the answer, thanks for reminding.